# Show sqlite query results in a TEdit - Firemonkey Mobile application?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, firedac

I have an sqlite database and i want to execute a select query and show the result in the TEdit. How can i do it?

```
 query := 'SELECT username FROM users';  //The query returns only one row
 FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
 FDQuery1.Open();
 Edit1.Text := ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, because you only have 1 column I would use:

```
Edit1.Text := FDQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
```

But if you have mulitple column you select I would use:

```
Edit1.Text := FDQuery1.fieldbyname(<ColumnName>).AsString;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Edit1.Text := FDQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
```

Please note that `ExecSQL` executes an SQL statement that does not return data, while `Open` executes a `SELECT` query.
So you are executing the query twice.

Comment: what's happen if the query will return no rows?

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

ExecSQL haven't return value

Examp:

```
 FDQuery1.sql.add:= 'SELECT username FROM users';
 FDQuery1.Open();

 Edit1.Text := FieldByName('username').AsString;
```